# Issue with json schema oneOf validation ... Not able to get the right validation

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I need help in validating json object with following constraint.

My object has four sub objects.

Valid Objects

- `{"obj" : { "obj1" : {}, "obj2" : {} } }`
- `{"obj" : { "obj1" : {}, "obj3" : {} } }`
- `{"obj" : { "obj1" : {}, "obj4" : {} } }`
- `{"obj" : { "obj1" : {} } }`

Invalid objects

- `{"obj" : { "obj1" : {}, "obj3" : {}, "obj4" : {} } }`
- `{"obj" : { "obj1" : {}, "obj2" : {}, "obj4" : {} } }`
- `{"obj" : { "obj1" : {}, "obj2" : {}, "obj3" : {} } }`
- `{"obj" : { "obj1" : {}, "obj2" : {}, "obj3" : {}, "obj4" : {} } }`

Only one out of obj2, obj3, obj4 can be present or none should be present.

Comment: Please provide your full schema, which shows what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressing mutually exclusive properties is pretty straightforward.

```
"oneOf": [
  { "required": ["obj2"] },
  { "required": ["obj3"] },
  { "required": ["obj4"] }
]
```

The tricky part is the "or none" constraint. You have to add a schema to the `oneOf` that forbids all the properties. There are a couple ways to do this, but I think the following is the cleanest if not the most straightforward.

```
"oneOf": [
  {
    "properties": {
      "obj2": false,
      "obj3": false,
      "obj4": false
    }
  },
  { "required": ["obj2"] },
  { "required": ["obj3"] },
  { "required": ["obj4"] }
]
```

An alternative is to use `dependencies` instead of `oneOf`.

```
"dependencies": {
  "obj2": { "not": { "required": ["obj3"] } },
  "obj3": { "not": { "required": ["obj4"] } },
  "obj4": { "not": { "required": ["obj2"] } }
}
```

It's much less code and scales better, but it's not immediately clear what it's doing or how/why it works (it does work, I promise).